# Jquery - cycling within a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, setinterval

Relative newcomer to JS trying to keep my code class-oriented for the sake of best practice. I found a piece of code [here](https://codepen.io/maaviles/pen/olKxr) for a text cycling effect I wanted to employ on a project. Using the code as-is within my main App.js worked fine. I then attempted to make it class/module oriented for later possible recycling, but thus far I've hit a brick wall. Passing console logs instead I've noticed that my attempts to use SetInterval, both within the class and in my App.js file calling the class into my HTML, don't seem to work, never properly looping more than once outside of isolating it.

Here's the current state of my code, possibly far removed from what I was doing previously, but it should give an idea where my head's at.

TextCycle.js:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class TextCycle{
constructor(){
    this.cycledText = $('.cycled-text');
    this.i = 0;
}

cycle(){
    //this.cycledText.removeClass('cycled-text--active');
    //this.cycledText.eq(this.i).addClass('cycled-text--active');
    this.i++;
    console.log(this.i);
}
}
export default TextCycle;
```

App.js:

```
import TextCycle from './components/TextCycle';

var textCycle = new TextCycle();

setInterval(textCycle.cycle(), 3000);
```

Given I have a working version this isn't a critical issue, but given the point was practicing this sort of JS organization and modularization due to how I was taught, any insight on making this work is immensely helpful!

Comment: Well the one comment I have is that if you're going to bother to make a class, why statically assign `this.cycledText`? At least pass the class to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the way you're using `setInterval()` , along with your call to `.cycle()`.

In short, you will want to update your code that calls `setInterval` so that `cycle()` is only called during the callback. Something like this would do:

```
setInterval(function() { textCycle.cycle() }, 3000);
```

One of the reasons your current code fails is that, `textCycle.cycle()` is called immediately, during this line:

```
setInterval(textCycle.cycle(), 3000); // Notice the () after cycle? 
                                      // That's causing the cycle 
                                      // method to be called immediately
```

By placing this in a callback function, as shown above, this does a few things:

- it ensures that `cycle()` is invoked from the correct context (ie the context of your `textCycle` object. That basically means that when your use `this` inside of `cycle()`, then `this` will be the `textCycle` object, rather than the global object
- it ensures that the `cycle()` method only gets invoked during the `setInterval` "callback", which is called on your set internal, rather than being called immediately

Hope this helps!

Comment: This has fixed part of the issue, namely the loop not going through, and I was able to modify it with the expression in the original code to increment up to as long as this.cycledText is. All that leaves is utilizing it to apply the classes, which doesn't seem to work with my existing code. Thank you for the help thus far!